# How to perform animation in javascript and html/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate two table rows so that when the total value of the second row becomes less than the first row, the two rows will interchange position. When I hardcode the id of the tr element the animation performs perfectly. However, if I dynamically give the id of the table row the animation is getting messed up as the bottom row is pushing the top row in the upwards direction. I am adding the table rows at runtime so the tbody given below is empty.The level[i] contains "b". Any help would be appreciated. I am using jquery 1.4.4.

js

```
//Not working
$("#" + level[i] + "row").animate({ top: '-50px' }, 2000, function () {
      $("#" + level[i] + "row").prev().animate({ top: '50px' }, 2000, function () {
        });
}); 

//working
$("#brow").animate({ top: '-50px' }, 2000, function () {
       $("#brow").prev().animate({ top: '50px' }, 2000, function () {
       });
});
```

Html table

```
<table id="main_table" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Level</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="messagesList"></tbody>
 </table>
```

Output:
Working
[image: Working output image]

Incorrect animation
[image: Incorrect output]

**UPDATE**
So i understood what the issue was.**The animation is not occuring as soon as the animate function is hit**. Basically i am dispatching a custom event in a for loop which will call the animate function and the  loop will only iterate if my rows are not in correct order. But since the rows are not animating immediately and **not setting in the correct order** the animate function is being called twice and is affecting both the rows instead of just affecting one. So is there a way i can make the animation happen as soon as the animate function is hit?

Comment: Post your code on where `level` gets populated with values.

Comment: can you add your code or create a fiddle

Comment: @GetSet Do you need the contents of the level array?

Comment: @AkhilAravind https://jsfiddle.net/xh0tybc9/

Comment: did you tried adding class to them

Comment: @GetSet "*level[i] contains "b"*"

Comment: @AkhilAravind which class?

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery library for animation

https://blog.bitsrc.io/11-javascript-animation-libraries-for-2018-9d7ac93a2c59